# How to run Keras on a CPU and a GPU simultaneously?

Tags: tensorflow, parallel-processing, keras, recurrent-neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am training a model consisting of a CNN and an RNN with to different inputs, the output of which will be fed to an FCN. Now the question:

Can I run the CNN on CPU and RNN on GPU in parallel?

as in Tensorflow:

```
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    CNN...
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    RNN...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use exactly the code you posted.

Select the device, define the layers, select another device, define other layers:

Now, the best performance will probably use the opposite:

```
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    CNNKerasLayers....
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    RNNKerasLayers....
```

Now, I'm not sure how keras will handle this (effectively parallel or not), but it will very probably just let tensorflow solve it.

Comment: I don't know about the RNN being faster on a CPU. I have a relatively simple RNN with 500 neurons and about 27 million datapoints. That takes ages to run for even 50 epochs on a GTX 1050 Ti. Then again, a CNN is pretty heavy too.

Comment: RNNs in GPUs are totally bad. Now CNNs on GPUs are great. You could test the RNN alone with CPU and GPU to confirm. (There are newer versions of RNNs like `CuDNNGRU` and `CuDNNLSTM` that may be faster on GPU).

Comment: Hmm funny. Wish I'd known that before I started my research. Thanks though!